# Specify Point Style in ListPlot in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot, point

Considering

```
dacount = {{0, 69}, {1, 122}, {2, 98}, {3, 122}, {4, 69}}

ListPlot[dacount, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, 
         PlotMarkers ->Automatic
         PlotStyle-> Lighter[Red, #] & /@ Range[0.5, 1, 0.1],
         Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.8], 
         PlotRange -> {{-1, 4.5}, {0, 192}}]
```

[image]

My hope there was for each point to take a different shade of red. 
But I can`t understand how to have a style for point which I tried to set as different list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your original code, the PlotStyle option won't affect the marker symbols, so you can leave it out. Instead, change your PlotMarkers option to the following:

```
PlotMarkers ->  With[{markerSize =  0.04}, 
 {Graphics[{Lighter[Red, #], Disk[]}], markerSize} & /@ Range[0.5, 1, 0.1]]
```

This will not yet have the desired effect until you replace the list dacount by:

```
Map[List, dacount]
```

By increasing the depth of the point list in this way, each point is assigned a marker style of its own from the list in PlotMarkers. So the final code is:

```
ListPlot[Map[List, dacount], AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, 
 PlotMarkers -> 
  With[{markerSize = 
     0.04}, {Graphics[{Lighter[Red, #], Disk[]}], markerSize} & /@ 
    Range[0.5, 1, 0.1]], Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.8], PlotRange -> {{-1, 4.5}, {0, 192}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Strictly speaking, in the original code the `PlotStyle` option ***does affect*** the marker symbols but is not specified correctly. Try `ListPlot[List/@dacount,AxesOrigin->{-1,0},PlotMarkers->{{\[FilledCircle],12}},PlotStyle->(Lighter[Red,#]&/@Range[0.5,1,0.1]),Filling->Axis,FillingStyle->Opacity[0.8],PlotRange->{{-1,4.5},{0,192}}]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it the following way:

```
xMax = Max@dacount[[All, 1]];
Show@(ListPlot[{#}, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
     PlotStyle -> (RGBColor[{(#[[1]] + 5)/(xMax + 5), 0, 0}]), 
     Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.8], 
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 4.5}, {0, 192}}] & /@ dacount)
```

[image]

This plots each point in `dacount` individually and assigns it a shade of red depending on the `x` value. The plots are then combined with `Show`.

I've arbitrarily chosen a scaling and offset for the different shades. You can choose whatever you want, as long as you ensure that the max value is 1.